# Can I use ref argument in modport in systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog

As I know the ref argument is only used task or function. But
I found someone code in systemverilog Which is the ref is used in modport.

Can I use ref argument in modport in systemverilog?
Like this, 
    modport( ref xxx,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's in the [1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) LRM.

Comment: You have used up my quota of answers for your questions. Learning SystemVerilog, or any other language is not going to come simply by asking questions on a forum. You need to look for tutorials and examples, starting small and working your way up to more complex things. You will find that you don;t even need 50% of all the features in SystemVerilog to get your job done.

Comment: Yes I know it and do now, but sometime  I can't understand things in there